# Load bitmap into NSImage in C++

Tags: c++, macos, bitmap

I need to load common windows bitmap image in MAC version of some application. On Win I have this

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, fileName, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
DG::Picture pic(hBitmap);
img3D->SetPicture(pic);
```

But on MAC I should use `NSImage`.

I found out NSImage is in `<AppKit/NSImage.h>` in `AppKit.framework`. So I included the framework and headers, but it seems its all in objective-c, so I can't compile this (Parse Issue when "compiling" objc.h)

My project is in C++ and I'm compiling it that way.

Basically I just need to load the bitmap as `void*` data and pass it to call another framework.

Is there any way to use NSImage in C++ or simply load bitmap using system frameworks?

Thanks

Comment: So DG::Picture expects a void*? Is there any documentation on this class? What does it REALLY expect? an HBITMAP?  Is this library compilable for mac? If it is, what do the docs say about this parameter.

Comment: Just to clarify, HBITMAP is a Win32 platform specific thing.

Comment: Yes, it expects void*. In documentation is only - For Windows use HBITMAP, for MAC use NSImage. And that is everything... DG Lib is for MAC. Everything is working, I just dont know how to load bitmap on MAC.

Comment: And I take it you have already tried NSImage* img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file_path];
?